# Talend tRestClient Error

Tags: java, apache, talend

I keep on getting the below-mentioned error in tRESTClient.

> ```
> Exception in component tRESTClient
> ```
>
> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: IOException invoking https://www.websitename.com/api-v1/login: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.checkClientException(AbstractClient.java:582)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.preProcessResult(AbstractClient.java:564)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doResponse(WebClient.java:1144)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1094)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:894)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:865)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:428)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.post(WebClient.java:458)
>
> [WARN ]: org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {https://www.websitename.com/api-v1/login?}tRESTClient has thrown exception, unwinding now
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.doRunInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:649)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1093)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:894)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:865)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:428)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.post(WebClient.java:458)
>       at local_project.apicalltest_0_1.ApiCallTest.tWriteJSONField_1_InProcess(ApiCallTest.java:2062)
>       at local_project.apicalltest_0_1.ApiCallTest$1ThreadXMLField_tWriteJSONField_1_Out.run(ApiCallTest.java:563)
>       at local_project.apicalltest_0_1.ApiCallTest.tWriteJSONField_1_InProcess(ApiCallTest.java:2062)
>       at local_project.apicalltest_0_1.ApiCallTest$1ThreadXMLField_tWriteJSONField_1_Out.run(ApiCallTest.java:563)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: IOException invoking https://www.websitename.com/api-v1/login: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1376)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1360)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: IOException invoking https://www.websitename.com/api-v1/login: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1376)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1360)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:651)
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:651)
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.doRunInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:649)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1093)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1282)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:267)
>       ... 9 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1282)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:267)
>       at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
>       at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1332)
>       ... 12 more
>       at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
>       at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1332)
>       ... 12 more

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear? ***The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore. Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true***

Answer (score 0):

> The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore. Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true

The website you are trying to reach with SSL does not have a valid SSL certificate.  The message says the certificate CN does not match the website URL, which makes it invalid.

If you control the website, generate a valid certificate for it; otherwise you will have to override Java's security mechanism as described in the message. This is NOT recommended.